# Parse XML via OPENXML SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008, openxml

**Context:** I have an XML document below that I am trying to query in SQL Server 2008. I've followed the tips here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vy2Nv26UzAU and have a query that executes without errors however returns nulls in fields that are clearly not empty.

**Question:** Can someone please provide some pointers/troubleshooting hints as to why the query is returning null results? Is it an issue with the hierarchy path or data types?

Here is the XML Document:

```
<Order_Details>
<Selection_ID>2100</Selection_ID>
<Order_Details>
  <Able_To_Use>Y</Able_To_Use>
  <Purchase_ID>GF-00000001</Purchase_ID>
  <QTY>1</QTY>
  <Subdetails>
    <REGION_QTY>2</REGION_QTY>
    <Testing_NO>00.05.04.01.00</Testing_NO>
  </Subdetails>
</Order_Details>
<Order_Details>
  <Able_To_Use>Y</Able_To_Use>
  <Purchase_ID>GF-00000002</Purchase_ID>
  <QTY>1</QTY>
  <Subdetails>
    <REGION_QTY>2</REGION_QTY>
    <Testing_NO>00.05.04.01.034</Testing_NO>
  </Subdetails>
</Order_Details>
```

Here is the query:

```
--Declare a table variable to hold the data in single column of XML data type
DECLARE @xml_data XML

SELECT @xml_data=O
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Desktop\Important Docs & Links\Important     Documents\Python Scripts\separate_xml_doc.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as file_output(O)

DECLARE @xml_doc int

--Procedure below takes 2 parameters: 1) output parameter to store handle to xml document and 2) the xml document itself 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xml_doc OUTPUT, @xml_data

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@xml_doc,'/Order_Details/Order_Details/',2)
WITH (
        Able_To_Use nvarchar(10),
        Purchase_ID nvarchar(20),
        QTY int
        )

--This procedre removes the saved prepared xml document from memory once finished using 
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xml_doc
```

These are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your own attempt running, there's nothing more than one `/` to much:

```
FROM OPENXML(@xml_doc,'/Order_Details/Order_Details',2)
```

But this approach is outdated. `FROM OPENXML`, together with the SPs to prepare and to remove a document should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist).

The modern way for XML (since v2005 :-) ) is to use the native XML methods, the XML type provides:

```
--Declare a table variable to hold the data in single column of XML data type
DECLARE @xml_data XML

SELECT @xml_data=
N'<Order_Details>
<Selection_ID>2100</Selection_ID>
<Order_Details>
  <Able_To_Use>Y</Able_To_Use>
  <Purchase_ID>GF-00000001</Purchase_ID>
  <QTY>1</QTY>
  <Subdetails>
    <REGION_QTY>2</REGION_QTY>
    <Testing_NO>00.05.04.01.00</Testing_NO>
  </Subdetails>
</Order_Details>
<Order_Details>
  <Able_To_Use>Y</Able_To_Use>
  <Purchase_ID>GF-00000002</Purchase_ID>
  <QTY>1</QTY>
  <Subdetails>
    <REGION_QTY>2</REGION_QTY>
    <Testing_NO>00.05.04.01.034</Testing_NO>
  </Subdetails>
</Order_Details>
</Order_Details>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT @xml_data.value('(/Order_Details/Selection_ID/text())[1]','int') AS SelectionId
      ,od.value('(Able_To_Use/text())[1]','nchar(1)') AS AbleToUse
      ,od.value('(Purchase_ID/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS PurchaseId
      ,od.value('(QTY/text())[1]','int') AS Quantity
      ,od.value('(Subdetails/REGION_QTY/text())[1]','int') AS RegionQty
      ,od.value('(Subdetails/Testing_NO/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS TestingNo
FROM @xml_data.nodes('/Order_Details/Order_Details') A(od)
```

I pick various levels here.

- The `Selection_ID` can be taken from the variable directly.
- We can use `.nodes()` to retrieve a set of repeating elements
- We can use `.value()` with a XPath to grab into the elements and fetch their text nodes.

The code above is the most explicit. This can be put simpler, but it is a good idea with XML to keep it as explicit as possible. Just to demonstrate, what would work doo:

This query has the same result, but it is *not* recommended...

```
SELECT @xml_data.value('(//Selection_ID)[1]','int') AS SelectionId
      ,od.value('Able_To_Use[1]','nchar(1)') AS AbleToUse
      ,od.value('Purchase_ID[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS PurchaseId
      ,od.value('QTY[1]','int') AS Quantity
      ,od.value('(Subdetails/REGION_QTY)[1]','int') AS RegionQty
      ,od.value('(Subdetails/Testing_NO)[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS TestingNo
FROM @xml_data.nodes('/Order_Details/Order_Details') A(od)
```